# Latitude and longitude scraping using Xpath

Tags: xpath, screen-scraping, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to web data mining. I'm using Xpath trying to scrape images and latitude and longitudes from a map on the browser.The images are in a nested table the path to this series of images is giving me a problem.Also the latitude and longitude are in a script and i need to extract does anyone know how to go about this.

Here is my code for the images

```
    <?php
    $baseUrl='http://www.hassconsult.co.ke/';
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.hassconsult.co.ke/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=27&Itemid=74&send=5&ref_no=834/II&google=1');
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    foreach($xpath->query("//div[@id='mainbody']/table") as $table) {
    echo $xpath->query(".//img", $table)->item(0)->getAttribute('src'). "\n";
    echo $xpath->query(".//tr[3]/td/a/img", $table)->item(0)->getAttribute('src'). "\n";;
    }

    ?>

here is the table outline as shown using firebug for the images

    <div id="mainbody">
<table width="502" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" height="69">
<a href="/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=27&Itemid=74&send=5&ref_no=834/II&photo_no=1">
<img width="50" height="45" border="0" style="border:1px #993300 solid;" alt="logo" src="/images/photos/p569_1.jpg">
</a>
<a href="/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=27&Itemid=74&send=5&ref_no=834/II&photo_no=2">
<img width="50" height="45" border="0" style="border:1px #993300 solid;" alt="logo" src="/images/photos/p569_2.jpg">
</a>
<a href="/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=27&Itemid=74&send=5&ref_no=834/II&photo_no=3">
<img width="50" height="45" border="0" style="border:1px #993300 solid;" alt="logo" src="/images/photos/p569_3.jpg">
</a>
<a href="/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=27&Itemid=74&send=5&ref_no=834/II&photo_no=4">
<img width="50" height="45" border="0" style="border:1px #993300 solid;" alt="logo" src="/images/photos/p569_4.jpg">
</a>
<a href="/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=27&Itemid=74&send=5&ref_no=834/II&photo_no=5">
<img width="50" height="45" border="0" style="border:1px #993300 solid;" alt="logo" src="/images/photos/p569_5.jpg">
</a>
<a href="/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=27&Itemid=74&send=5&ref_no=834/II&photo_no=6">
<img width="50" height="45" border="0" style="border:1px #993300 solid;" alt="logo" src="/images/photos/p569_6.jpg">
</a>
<a href="/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=27&Itemid=74&send=5&ref_no=834/II&photo_no=7">
<img width="50" height="45" border="0" style="border:1px #993300 solid;" alt="logo" src="/images/photos/p569_7.jpg">
</a>
<div style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;color:#FF9900;padding-top:10px;"></div>
<strong>
<br>
<div style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#000000;text-align:justify;">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

here is the function that shows the geopoints as shown by firebug

```
    <tr>
<td>
<br>
<br>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 450px; height: 450px; position: relative; background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223);">
<script>
function initialize() {
if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
var point = new GLatLng(-1.242831, 36.777805);//how will i pick these values and echo
map.setCenter(point, 16);
map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
map.addControl(new GScaleControl());
map.setUIToDefault();
map.setMapType(G_NORMAL_MAP);
var marker = new GMarker(point);
map.addOverlay(marker);
GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {marker.openInfoWindowHtml('<h3>Hillview<br /><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=&daddr=' + point.toUrlValue() + '" target ="_blank">Get Directions<\/a>');});
}
}
window.onload = initialize;
window.onunload = GUnload;
</script>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use xpath to get the script contents but you will need (ideally a js parser) or regex to get those values:

```
$src = $xpath->query("//script")->item(0)->nodeValue;
preg_match('/GLatLng\(([\d.-]+), ([\d.-]+)\)/', $src, $m);
list(, $lat, $lng) = $m;
```